# How to add a new module dynamically?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, web

Image that I have the following `.js` code:

```
 $.ajax({
     url: 'some/url',
     success: function(result) {
        $activeTabContainer.html(result);
    }
 });
```

The `$activeTabContainer` is `jQuery` selected div.

The result object contains html (with script tag), maybe something like:

```
<div ng-app="mySpa">
    <div ng-controller="myController"></div>
</div>
```

And later in the same `.html` file a script tag, which contains:

```
(function () {
    "use strict";
    var app = angular.module("mySpa", []);
    app.controller("myController", [function () {
        debugger;
    }]);
})();
```

It perfectly executes the `.js` part in the script tag, but I guess that angular must be somehow notified about the dynamically added module and its controllers, something like dynamically bootstrapping.

Do anyone have an idea?

Comment: Don't mix angular and jQuery. The jQuery selected div is not accessible after angular is bootstrapped. You need to use angular's $http and coding convention.

Comment: I could literally count on one hand the number of times I've actually had to use jQuery in Angular - generally if you're reaching for that, it means you're doing something a suboptimal way.

Comment: @Hoyen I am not mixing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, it happens because angular does not bootstrap automatically, when a new module is added dynamically. You need to bootstrap it manually:

```
angular.bootstrap(document, ["mySpa"]);
```

And bingo it works :-)

Link to the documentation:
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.bootstrap